What is this yellow, 2-wire, through-hole, resistor-like component and how do i check it?
I'm looking at this pcb for a friend. I noticed that there are components that is orange and that look like resistors. There are many that look the same, but one is showing different value when testing the resistance.  Any idea on what it is and how to check it?



Looks like a multilayer ceramic capacitor to me.

Is there a silk screen item number, example R34?

Nothing on the silk screen

Here is a little tip. if it is a resistor, the body is blue/light brown and there are bands around the body. This one does not look like a resistor so it can be an axial lead mlcc (multi-layer ceramic capacitor) that others suggested

It's an axial-lead ceramic capacitor similar to this one. Probably they are mostly or entirely power supply bypass capacitors.

It should measure open-circuit on a resistance range when removed from the circuit. Capacitance can then be measured if it passes that test.

Based upon the 2nd picture in the question, the component are being used for power supply decoupling. This is based upon one lead being connected to the ground plane on the PCB via a PCB Thermal relief.
I'm not sure of the capacitor values as can't make out the full markings. Some example datasheet for such capacitor series:

Vishay Axial Leaded Multilayer Ceramic Capacitors for General Purpose
Kemet Axial Leaded Multilayer Ceramic Capacitors

